# Fetching asna redirect url parameter on google app engine in golang

Tags: google-app-engine, go, asana, asana-api, asana-connect

My asana oauth redirect URL is something like

**https://testapp.appspot.com/api/redirect.asana#access_token=123456789**

I am not sure how to fetch access_token now.

**Note :** *if I am changing ? to # then its working fine by using r.FormValue("access_token").*

Answer (score 1):

The reason why [`r.FormValue()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.FormValue) does not get it is because URL parameters are separated by `?` but in your URL it is not.

The `#` is used to separate a fragment for references, so your `access_token` should be in `r.URL.Fragment`... but it won't.

### You can't test it from the browser

Fragments are not sent over to the server, fragments are for the browsers. There was an issue covering this:

[net/http: document fields set in Request.URL in handler #3805](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/3805)

It is also included in the doc of [`http.Request`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request):

> For server requests the URL is parsed from the URI supplied on the Request-Line as stored in RequestURI. **For most requests, fields other than Path and RawQuery will be empty. (See RFC 2616, Section 5.1.2)**

### Code to get it from the request

If a non-browser client does send it as part of the request path, you can use simple `string` operations to get the token value: it is the part after the `=` character. You can use [`strings.Index()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Split) to find the `"="`:

```
raw := r.URL.Path
if idx := strings.Index(raw, "="); idx >= 0 && idx < len(raw)-1 {
    token := raw[idx+1:]
    fmt.Fprintln(w, "Token:", token)
}
```

Output:

```
Token: 123456789
```

As an alternative solution you can also use [`strings.Split()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Index) to split it by `"="`, 2nd element will be the value of the token:

```
parts := strings.Split(r.URL.Path, "=")
fmt.Fprintln(w, "Parts:", parts)
if len(parts) == 2 {
    fmt.Fprintln(w, "Token:", parts[1])
}
```

Output:

```
[/api/redirect.asana#access_token 123456789]
Token: 123456789
```

### Code to test it

Here is a code using [`net/http`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/) to call your server that will send a path being `"/api/redirect.asana#access_token=123456789"`, and it will print the response body to the standard output (console):

```
c := &http.Client{}
req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://localhost:8080/", nil)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
req.URL.Path = "/api/redirect.asana#access_token=123456789"
resp, err := c.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer resp.Body.Close()
io.Copy(os.Stdout, resp.Body)
```

Comment: But  raw := r.URL.String() is fetching only api/redirect.asana, I need complete url to be fetched for this code to work.

Comment: Your code is working only when I am changing # to ?. I think we are back to zero. In case of ? even r.FormValue("access_token") is sufficient.

Comment: Even r.URL.Fragment is blank so rest code will not work.

Comment: @NikhilMaheshwari Fragments are not sent over to the server. See edited answer. I also cleaned up my comments.

Comment: I was doing it manually, just to test how my handler will behave if its a ? instead of #, no way to change otherwise. As long as I can't get URL parameters, I can not do it. Thanks for the informative link in the answer but  I don't have control over the URL as it's a redirect URL from ASANA.

Comment: In that case, my very first answer stands. You can't test it from your browser, because the browser won't send the fragment. If it is coming from another server, you will most likely have it. Please test it in prod environment.

Comment: I can only change the redirect URL in my app in ASANA but ASANA is sending the access token by appending #access_token=.... to it.

Comment: @NikhilMaheshwari I reworked the answer. I included my original parsing code, also included code that you can use to test it (since you can't test it from browsers).